# Could you explain when use 'turn' when use 'grow'?

Tags: word-usage

Could you explain when use 'turn' when use 'grow' or they are the same anyway?
I do not feel the difference at least here and the like.

> And the fields have **turned** brown.
>   As the evening sky **grew** dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Turned** typically conveys a change from one state to another, perhaps without any transitional state, for example:

> The fields turned from green to brown.

> His face turned red with anger.

Whereas **grew** may describe the gradual transition to another state, as something develops e.g.:

> As winter approached, the nights grew long.

Comment: Although the distinction is only as clear as the situation. You could also say, "As summer turned to fall, the fields grew progressively browner."

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast A fair point, context is everything. Though your example still agrees with my description of changing from one thing to another, rather than progressing through gradations.

Answer (score 0):

This is in the dictionary. Grow means to become something and turn is used for growing things that turn color, usually foliage but really any plant as autumn comes.

Merriam Webster:
ENTRY: grow

: to pass into a condition : BECOME [caps not mine]
**grew pale**

Merriam Webster:
ENTRY: TURN

6a(1) : to make acid or sour

(2) : **to change the color of (foliage)**

[turn](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn)

[grow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grow?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)